# Browser window with error pops up when using azure access control from WPF client

Tags: facebook, authentication, azure, jwt

I am currently implementing azure access control as our default authentication platform for a number of different applications that we support both WPF clients and websites.

I am seeing the following strange behavior in a WPF client.

Using the Azure Authentication Library I am running the following lines of code to aquire a JWT token that is then used to authenticate to our services.

```
   _authContext = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Authentication.AuthenticationContext("https://xxxx.accesscontrol.windows.net");
    AssertionCredential credential = _authContext.AcquireToken("http://localhost/xxxx");
```

In testing we have no problems with Facebook authentication directly to the service our website they work fine. Google and Microsoft ID also work fine in both WEB and WPF situations.

However when using Facebook from one of our WPF clients a browser window pops up and the following error is displayed .

```
HTTP Error Code:  502  
Message:  ACS40000: An error occurred while processing a Facebook sign-in response. This may be caused by invalid configuration of the Facebook application.  
Inner Message:  ACS40001: An error occurred while attempting to get an access token from Facebook.  
Inner Message:  ACS90005: Web exception  
Trace ID:  1a8a9ddf-5bf7-4c09-ace2
Timestamp:  XXXXXXX
```

As per the suggestion of similar looking error found on stackoverflow I've reset my facebook application settings but cannot seem to find a final answer